# BigQuery slow on simple query

Tags: google-bigquery

Lately I've noticed that BigQuery is slow on a simple query, single table, without joins. It takes a minute and more to execute the following query on a table with 9000 rows:

```
SELECT 
 max(repeatedElement1) as elem1, 
 max(repeatedElement2) as elem2, 
 max(repeatedElement3) as elem3, 
FROM myTable 
WHERE id = '543978b4e4b09bccb70c7473'
```

Exact query is 507322187707:job_rDMpbbAUjpsGsv-jTxaVJU-gRRg

IIRC, this used to take much less time to execute.

Comment: The only page that I know of right now is the [bigquery-downtime-notify page](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/bigquery-downtime-notify). Other than that, I watch on [Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-bigquery) if other have a similar problem. I also watch the [BigQuery issues page](https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/list) where users can report bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the logs for your query, and it looks like you're hitting a performance bug in bigquery (we're taking far too long before actually starting the query). We've fixed this (and several other performance issues) in the next release, which will hopefully go out on wednesday of this week, but may be later than that if we find regressions.

I'll try to remember to update this thread with the status, but if I don't, feel free to ping me.

Comment: This bug has been fixed for several weeks now. If you see poor performance, please let us know, it is likely a different issue.